# Identify PathParam inside an Undertow filter when the response entity is a String

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, resteasy, undertow

I need to identify @PathParam from a request, inside an undertow filter, to ignore them (metrics purpose).

My filter looks like this:

```
public class MetricsHandler implements HttpHandler {

    private HttpHandler next;

    public MetricsHandler(HttpHandler next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
        MetricsListener listener = new MetricsListener();
        exchange.addExchangeCompleteListener(listener);
        next.handleRequest(exchange);
    }

    private class MetricsListener implements ExchangeCompletionListener {
        @Override
        public void exchangeEvent(HttpServerExchange exchange, NextListener nextListener) {
            try {
                String metric = exchange.getRequestURI();
                UriInfo uriInfo = ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(UriInfo.class);
                /*
                 * When the response entity is a String, this UriInfo is null at this point. If it's another type, the UriInfo is ok and i'm able to identify path parameters ...
                 */
                if(uriInfo != null) {
                    Collection<List<String>> pathParametersValues = uriInfo.getPathParameters(false).values();
                    for (List<String> list : pathParametersValues) {
                        for (String pathParameter : list) {
                            metric = metric.replace("/"+pathParameter, "");
                        }
                    }
                }

                Metrics.increment(metric);
            } finally {
                if (nextListener != null) {
                    nextListener.proceed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This filter is packaged as a wildfly module and configured in domain.xml (Wildfly 10.1.0), inside the undertow subsystem, as follows:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <filter-ref name="metricsFilter"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <filters>
                <filter class-name="com.metrics.filter.MetricsHandler" module="com.metrics" name="metricsFilter"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
```

And here are my REST methods:

```
@GET
@Path("/path/num/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response pathNum(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return Response.ok(123).build();
}

@GET
@Path("/path/string/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response pathString(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return Response.ok("abc").build();
}
```

I'm able to identify the "id" path parameter when requesting for pathNum method, but I'm not for the pathString one. As of the comment, calling ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(UriInfo.class) returns null for the pathString method.

I've tested this behavior against resteasy 3.0.19.Final, 3.0.20.Final and 3.0.22.Final, all with the same results.

Debugging resteasy I found that, when the response entity is Integer or another type, the MessageBodyWriter is ResteasyJackson2Provider (my rest @Produces json), and SynchronousDispatcher.clearContextData is called only after my filter's ExchangeCompletionListener.exchangeEvent.

BUT, when the response entity is a String, the MessageBodyWriter is a StringTextStar and the clearContextData is called after the MessageBodyWriter and **before** my ExchangeCompletionListener, so there is no more contextData to look.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a possible bug on resteasy, or on wildfly...